# Can I add a Jython action listener to a java program?

Tags: java, jython, actionlistener

I have a Java program which I'd like to call from a Jython program. I'd like to be able to have the two interface with one another and had hoped to call the Java program from Jython with an action listener as a parameter, but so far I have had no luck.

Jython code:

```
import sys
sys.path.append("sgJython.jar")
from java.awt.event import ActionListener
from java.awt.event import ActionEvent
from sg.gui import MainGui

class MyListener(ActionListener):
    def ActionPerformed(e):
          print("gotit")

ml = MyListener()
MainGui(ml)
```

Java code:

```
package sg;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
class MainGui
{
public MainGui(ActionListener listener)
{
    top = new JFrame();
    top.setBounds(300, 300, 600, 300);
    JButton doneButton = new JButton("Done");
    doneButton.addActionListener(listener);
    top.add(doneButton)
}
}
```

Is there some other way of doing this? If not, is there a better way to go about integrating Java and Python into a single application, or is that not a good thing to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way it is already works, you just have to fix the `actionPerformed` method, which has a wrong signature and which does not declare the `self` parameter.

```
class MyListener(ActionListener):
    def actionPerformed(self, e):
          print("gotit")
```

In your Java code, you missed a couple of semicolons and since you are not displaying the frame it will not be visible unless you explicitly ask it from your Jython code. So I changed it a bit for testing purposes:

```
public class MainGui {

    private JFrame top;

    public MainGui(ActionListener listener) {
        top = new JFrame();
        top.setBounds(300, 300, 600, 300);
        JButton doneButton = new JButton("Done");
        doneButton.addActionListener(listener);
        top.add(doneButton);
        top.pack();
        top.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

I did the Java code in a Java Project in Eclipse and the Python code in PyDev project in Eclipse, then I ran the Python script and it worked like a charm.

Comment: Thanks for your help. The misspelling was a problem, and the print statement did not work correctly in this context from within my IDE (JHepWork). It does work now though. Thanks again.